# Fetching JavaScript array elements after consecutive occurrence of an element

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a JavaScript array like:

```
var myArray = ['a', 'x', 'b', 'x', 'x', 'p', 'y', 'x', 'x', 'b', 'x', 'x'];
```

I want to fetch only those elements of the array that come after 2 consequent occurrences of a particular element.

i.e. in the above array, I want to fetch all the elements that come after consequent `'x', 'x'`

So my output should be:

```
'p'
'b'
```

I have a solution like :

```
var arrLength = myArray.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrLength; i++) {
    if(i+2 < arrLength && myArray[i] == 'x' && myArray[i+1] == 'x') {
        console.log(myArray[i+2]);
    }
};
```

This satisfies my needs, but it is not so generic.

For eg. if I have to check for 3 consequent occurrences, then again I have to add a condition inside **if** for `myArray[i+2] == 'x'` and so on.

Could anyone provide a better way to fetch the elements?

Comment: What if you have 4 `'x'`? If the 3rd fetched? Do the 3rd and the 4rt fetch the following item?

Comment: Are the array elements always single letters? This is essentially a string problem (with many good and efficient solutions), though none of them is natively implemented on `Array`

Comment: @Bergi, I want a generic solution so this array may contain a single letter or might be an array of strings.

Comment: @Oriol, Yes, Both item should be fetched.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The functional way would be to use recursion. With an ES6 spread, you can pretty much emulate the terseness of a truly 'functional' language :-)

```
var myArray = ['a', 'x', 'b', 'x', 'x', 'p', 'y', 'x', 'x', 'b', 'x', 'x'];

function reducer(acc, xs) {
    if (xs.length > 2) {
        if (xs[0] === xs[1]) {
            // add the third element to accumulator
            // remove first three elements from xs
            // return reducer([xs[2], ...acc], xs.slice(3));
            // or per Nina's question below
            return reducer([xs[2], ...acc], xs.slice(1));
        } else {
            // remove first element from xs and recurse
            return reducer(acc, xs.slice(1))
        }
    } else {
        return acc;
    }
}

console.log(reducer([], myArray));
```

Comment: Recursion is a heavily recurrent mechanism in functional languages. And this code really does emulate functional programming very well -- no procedural/imperative code except for `slice()`, which can be reproduced in functional languages anyway.

Comment: please test this array: `['a', 'x', 'b', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'p', 'y', 'x', 'x', 'b', 'x', 'x']` with tripple `'x'`, expected result: `[ 'x', 'p', 'b']`

Comment: Easily accommodated, if that is the expected result of the algorithm, see Oriol's comment to OP

Comment: I was just assuming that. ty

Comment: Recursion is when a function calls itself. To avoid an infinite loop, it must call itself with an ever smaller input (that's what slicing off the first element achieves) and then when it has run out of input it has to stop and return something (the accumulator in this case). Recursion is very popular in functional approaches to programming, and efficient recursion is now part of Javascript 2015 so you can expect to see much more of it in the future http://www.2ality.com/2015/06/tail-call-optimization.html

Comment: Could you please add a little bit more comments on what this line is for:return reducer([xs[2], ...acc], xs.slice(1));

Comment: `[xs[2], ...acc]` puts xs[3] in front of the existing elements of acc (`...` is also part of javascript 2015); `xs.slice(1)` returns xs but without the first element.

Comment: So in my case just adding acc.push(xs[2]) will produce my expected result. Thanks for your solution.

Answer (score 3):

A generic straight forward approach for any comparable content.

```js
function getParts(array, pattern) {
    return array.reduce(function (r, a, i) {
        i >= pattern.length && pattern.every(function (b, j) {
            return b === array[i + j - pattern.length];
        }) && r.push(a);
        return r;
    }, []);
}

function p(o) {
    document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(o, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
}

p(getParts(['a', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'p', 'y', 'x', 'x', 'b', 'x', 'x'], ['x', 'x']));
p(getParts(['a', 'x', 'b', 'x', 'x', 'p', 'y', 'x', 'x', 'b', 'x', 'x'], ['a', 'x', 'b']));
p(getParts(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'z', 'y', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'x', 'x'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']));
p(getParts([41, 23, 3, 7, 8, 11, 56, 33, 7, 8, 11, 2, 5], [7, 8, 11]));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try following logic

```js
var myArray = ['a', 'x', 'b', 'x', 'x', 'p', 'y', 'x', 'x', 'b', 'x', 'x'];

function search(ch, times) {
  var splitStr = "";  
  for(var i = 0; i < times; i++) {
   splitStr += ch;
  } // Generate the split string xx in the above case.
  var str = myArray.join(''); // Join array items into a string
  var array = str.split(splitStr); // Split the string based on split string
  var result = {};
  // iterate on the array starting from index 1 as at index 0 will be string before split str
  for (var i = 1 ; i < array.length; i++) { 
     if(array[i] !== "") {
        result[array[i].substring(0,1)] = ''; // A map in order to avoid duplicate values
     }
  }
  
  return Object.keys(result); // return the keys
}

console.dir(search('x',2));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create an additional function `isItGood` like this:

```js
var myArray = ['a', 'x', 'b', 'x', 'x', 'p', 'y', 'x', 'x', 'b', 'x', 'x'];
var arrLength = myArray.length;
for (var i = 0; i < arrLength; i++) {
    isItGood(myArray, i, 'x', 2);
};

function isItGood(arr, i, elem, total) {
    for ( var j = 0 ; j < total ; j++ ) {
        if ( i + total >= arr.length || arr[i+j] != elem ) {
            return;
        }
    }
    console.log(arr[i+total]);
    // just to see the result (no need to open a console)
    document.getElementById('p').innerHTML+=("<br/>"+arr[i+total]);
}
```

```html
<p id="p">Result: </p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a straightforward iterative solution.  We maintain an array `consecutive` of consecutive elements.  If that array gets to length 2, then the next element is printed and `consecutive` is reset.

```
var arr = ['a', 'x', 'b', 'x', 'x', 'p', 'y', 'x', 'x', 'b', 'x', 'x'];

var REPEATS_NEEDED = 2;

var consecutive = [arr[0]];
for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (consecutive.length === REPEATS_NEEDED) {
        console.log(arr[i]);
        consecutive = [arr[i]];
        continue;
    }

    // either add to or reset 'consecutive'
    if (arr[i] === consecutive[0]) {
        consecutive.push(arr[i]);
    } else {
        consecutive = [arr[i]];
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `for` loop using variables referencing previous index, current index, next index of array

```js
var myArray = ["a", "x", "b", "x", "x", "p", "y", "x", "x", "b", "x", "x"];

for (var res = [], curr = 0, prev = curr - 1, match = curr + 1
    ; curr < myArray.length - 1; curr++, prev++, match++) {
  if (myArray[curr] === myArray[prev]) res.push(myArray[match]);
};

console.log(res);
document.body.textContent = res;
```

Answer (score 2):

If I had to write this in Scala instead of JavaScript I could just do it in one line.
`myArray.sliding(3).filter(l => l(0) == 'x' && l(1) == 'x').map(l => l(2))`

So I guess I could do it the same way in JS if I implement the sliding function myself.
e.g.

```
function sliding(array, n, step) {
  if(!step) step = 1;
  var r = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < array.length - n + 1; i += step) {
    r.push(array.slice(i, i + n));
  }
  return r;
}
var result = sliding(myArray, 3).filter(l => l[0] === "x" && l[1] === "x").map(l => l[2]);
```

The only downside here is that this runs slower than a more iterative approach. But that only matters for very big arrays.